# How do I compare the output with a string in java?

Tags: java

I have written a program that gives an output like

"bbccaa"

Is there a way in java to store this into a sting and compare to another string.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'gives an output' ? Does it print the string to the console?

Assuming that you have something like:

```
String s = ...; // Something that creates bbccaa
System.out.println(s);
```

Then you can just do:

```
s.equals(otherString);
```

to compare the two strings

Answer (score 1):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` or `equals()` to **compare 2 String objects**....

```
String s = "hello";

String sOutput = "bbccaa";

if (sOutput.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){   // Ignore case while comparing


 }


if (sOutput.equals(s)){            // Consider case while comparing


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
"bbccaa".equals(anotherString)
```

or

```
"bbccaa".compareTo(anotherString)
```

---

**See**

- [`String` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

How is this string generated?
If you use Streams you save the stream as a string and use the equals-Method

Comment: Why does it matter how the string is generated. The only safe way to compare strings is using `equals`.